# jQuery Mobile - Change highlight color of toggleswitch

Tags: jquery-mobile, highlight, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

Sorry, but I just cannot make it..
I have this toggleswitch: http://oi44.tinypic.com/345en4m.jpg
Created like this:

```
<div id="switch">
  <select name="toggleswitch1" id="toggleswitch1" data-theme="" data-track-theme="e" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off"> Offline </option>
    <option value="on"> Online </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And I want to change the font and color of this "Online"-Option. I already changed the Offline-Option with `data-track-theme="e"`.

I also changed the highlight color of normal sliders like this:

```
div.ui-btn-active {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #ffefaa ),to( #ffe155 ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffefaa,#ffe155 );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( #ffefaa,#ffe155 );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( #ffefaa,#ffe155 );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( #ffefaa,#ffe155 );
  background-image: linear-gradient( #ffefaa,#ffe155 )
}
```

But I just cannot get this "Offline"-Option. :(

Could someone tell me how to reach it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo CSS selector `first-child` to override style of first option in the toggle switch.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/CvN48/)**

```
div.ui-slider span:first-child {
  /* Your styles here following each property with !important */
}
```

You can also do it jQuery way.

```
$('[role=application] span:first-child').addClass('online');
```

`.online` is a custom style.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Hs9cN/)**